# Is there a way to create Marketo webhooks via API?

Tags: marketo

I'm looking to see if there's a way to create webhooks with Marketo via their API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to define Webhooks via the Marketo user interface. Once created, you can create a Smart Campaign that calls the Webhook (via the UI also) and request that Smart Campaign via the API.